# how do i sum all results that match criteria on 2 axis

Tags: excel, vba

I have a grid with variable headers on the X and Y axis and values under some of those (think of an old distance to - from in the back of an old MAP) with the same headers on both axis however some headers will be repeated. i want to sum all the matches on my given singular criteria of the header
i.e. `a b c` along the top `a b a c a d` along the side and various number filling in the grid I want to count all where a is the header on both axis

I have tried various sum, match, index, UDF  Functions that i cant seem to get right

```
=SUM(INDEX(C4:P35,MATCH("SICK",C4:C35,0),MATCH("SICK",C4:P4,)))
```

This seems to return the first match but not sum any subsequent matches

I expect the sum to return all the matches to the index rather than the first

Comment: Sum two SUMIFs, one for the horizontal and the other for the vertical then subtract the value where they intersect to remove the duplicate(hint: your formula above returns the intersecting)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
=SUMPRODUCT($D$5:$P$35*($C$5:$C$35="SICK")*($D$4:$P$4="SICK"))
```

Comment: now if i wanted to exclude where color.index=4 . how can i incorporate that ? i have made a custom UDF to sum on colour  for another separate sum

Comment: @CraigBooth Please start a new question for that.  Include sample data and expected results along with the code of the custom UDF and the formula(s) you tried.